# Conditionally Target Outlook 2007/2010/2013, But Not Outlook.com

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook.com

I know we can conditionally target Outlook '07-'13, but it seems that Outlook.com also matches my condition.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!--><br /><!--<![endif]-->
```

Is there a better code for this statement to where it does not match Outlook.com?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Why post an answer with an "i dunno."?

Anyway, Outlook.com prepends all of your classes with ecx. What I like to do is make make the td 0 height (`height="0" style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px;"`), add your class `class="outlookthing"` and in your `<style>` correct for the 0 height with a `td[class="ecxoutlookthing]{font-size:XXpx; line-height:XXpx; height:XXpx;}`

Comment: I forgot to mention that outlook.com strips comments, and the contents of opened / closed conditional comments, which most clients do not. Hence my solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way of accomplishing this; may have to take a look at the HTML to figure out what's causing this and another way to do it.

Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
                <xsl:comment>
                    <![CDATA[[if  mso 12]>Contents for 2007<![endif]]]>
                </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:comment>
                    <![CDATA[[if  mso 14]>Contents for 2010<![endif]]]>
                </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:comment>
                    <![CDATA[[if  mso 15]>Contents for 2013<![endif]]]>
                </xsl:comment>
```